# regex select all string exept string in the end

Tags: regex

I want regex to select all string except "html" string to the end 
or select full string if "html" not found for example:this string

> yurry/nova-gta-flowers-html-html.html

or

> yurry/nova-gta-flowers.html

`^([^/]*)/(.*?).(?=html)`       this select yurry/nova-gta-flowers

I created this regex is working fine select all string except html string to the end
my problem is if there is no "html" string this will cause my regex to not select full string for example:

> yurry/nova-gta-flowers
>    my regex select nothing

Comment: Is the regex working correctly for the first string? I mean, do you need to select `yurry/nova-gta-flowers-`?

Comment: Why use regular expressions. Just chop off the last five characters and check that it is `.html`? Seems simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this regex:

```
^([^/]*)/((?:.(?!html))*)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aG4mN6)

`(?:.(?!html))*` will match any character except `html` and leave the last character.

Comment: @user3162193 Put comments by clicking the [add comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931904/regex-select-all-string-exept-string-in-the-end/20932123#) link please instead of editing the answer. If it worked for you, you can [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/204922).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this:

```
^([^/]*)/(.*?)(\Whtml)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Match the start of the string
([^/]*) # Match any number of non-slash characters --> group 1
/       # Match a slash
(.*?)   # Match any characters, as few as possible --> group 2
(?:     # Match but don't capture...
 \W     #  one non-alphanumeric character (like . or -)
 html   #  "html"
)*      # any number of times, including zero
$       # Match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

First mistake, the dot before html must be escaped.

Last block must be optionnal, including the dot.

```
^([^/]*)/(.*?)(\.html)?
```

But it would be simplier to check if the string ends with .html and removing it if needed.

Comment: You also need an anchor, or the match will always end at the `/`.

Comment: ^([^/]*)/(.*?)(\.html)?   not work
I want to not select all html not just .html in the end
for example:
yurry/nova-gta-flowers-html-html.html
will select only yurry/nova-gta-flowers

Comment: Yep, thank, I misunderstood. But Jerry give the good one in his answer